# Have one div replace another on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs that are different sizes, D1 and D2.  when hovering over D1 I want D2 to become visible, and D1 to come back when the user moves off.  So D2 should replace D1 when the user hovers.

If you try the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/birby/27tda5m9/44/), you'll see the problem.  The blocks flash and D2 never becomes visible.

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
    
#inBack {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
    
#inFront :hover {
    display:none;
}
    
#inBack :hover {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" >
    <div id="inFront"  style="background-color:red;" class="navi">
        <h2>
          header of item in front
        </h2>
        <text>
          <p>body of item in front</p>
          <p>body of item in front</p>
        </text>
    </div>
      
    <div id="inBack"  style="background-color:green; display:none;" >
        <h2>
          header of item in back
        </h2>
        <text>
          <p>body of item in back</p>
          <p>body of item in back</p>
          <p>body of item in back</p>
          <p>body of item in back</p>
          <p>body of item in back</p>
          <p>body of item in back</p>
        </text>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div style="background-color:cyan;">
    <p>
    This part should be pushed down to make way for the larger text
    </p>
   
</div>
```

Do I need javascript for this?

Comment: Your D1 shrinks on hover, so it's not being hovered on anymore so it grows again until you're hovering again.  That's why you get that effect.  Try wrapping it in a div and use hover on that to control the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wrap the back/front elements in one more div than it is a lot simpler to show/hide. but if back is smaller than front, you will get the bouncing effect.

```css
.wrapper2:hover #inFront {
  display: none;
}

.wrapper2:hover #inBack {
  display: block;
}

#inFront {
  background-color: red;
}

#inBack {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div id="inFront" style="background-color:red;" class="navi">
      <h2>
        header of item in front
      </h2>
      <text>
      <p>body of item in front</p>
      <p>body of item in front</p>
    </text>
    </div>

    <div id="inBack">
      <h2>
        header of item in back
      </h2>
      <text>
      <p>body of item in back</p>
      <p>body of item in back</p>
      <p>body of item in back</p>
      <p>body of item in back</p>
      <p>body of item in back</p>
      <p>body of item in back</p>
    </text>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color:cyan;">
  <p>
    This part should be pushed down to make way for the larger text
  </p>

</div>
```